# How to place two ctables side by side

Tags: tables, positioning, subfloats, minipage, ctable

*[`ctable`](ftp://ctan.tug.org/ctan/macros/latex2e/contrib/ctable/ctable.pdf)*, not a regular `table`/`tabular`.

How can I get two narrow ctables to go side by side? I want them to be subtables of a larger table, just two independent tables side by side. I've tried using a table, minipage, subfig—I keep getting the error `not in outer par mode`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set the `pos` option to `H` (from the `float` package) then you can enclose your `ctable`s inside `minipages`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\ctable[caption = Two ctables side by side,
label = tab:test1,
width = 5cm,pos= H,left]{c>{\raggedright}X}{
\tnote{footnotes are placed under the table}
}{
\ML
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Multicolumn entry!}
\NN
\midrule
one&
The width of this column depends on the width of the table.\tmark
}
\end{minipage}%THIS COMMENT IS SIGNIFICANT
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\ctable[caption = Two ctables side by side,
label = tab:test2,
width = 5cm,pos= H,left]{c>{\raggedright}X}{
\tnote{footnotes are placed under the table}
}{
\ML
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Multicolumn entry!}
\NN
\midrule
one&
The width of this column depends on the width of the table.\tmark
}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, now your tables are *not* floating objects so their correct placement is your responsibility.

Comment: "%THIS COMMENT IS SIGNIFICANT", why?